# Update Windows Azure Endpoint with load balancer probe settings

Tags: powershell, azure, load-balancing, endpoint, probe

I am trying to update the probe settings for a load balanced endpoint in windows azure but facing

> "Update-AzureVM : Failed: The server encountered an internal error. Please retry the request."

Since probe settings for endpoints are not accessible through the web GUI I am using the PowerShell cmdlets to achieve this. I have followed the guide here
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/common-tasks/how-to-load-balance-virtual-machines/#lbprobes

I have also tried with adding a new endpoint with cmdlet `Add-AzureEndpoint` and updating a existing endpoint with `Set-AzureEndpoint`. The commands executed is:

> Get-AzureVM -Name "web-server-01" -ServiceName "web-servers" | Add-AzureEndpoint -LBSetName "Web_80" -Name "Web" -Protocol "tcp" -LocalPort 80 -PublicPort 80 -ProbePort 80 -ProbePath "/ping" -ProbeProtocol http | Update-AzureVM

Is there anyone familiar with the problem and has succeeded updating the probe settings or knows how to get more out of the error message generated?

Comment: Did you ever end up getting it to work? The provided cmdlet is not working properly when I try it.

Comment: Yes, I think something changed in the backend processing the requests and it just started working. Same command as above.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem when I try to get the endpoints for a VM using:

```
Get-AzureVM –ServiceName “XXX” –Name “XXX” | Get-AzureEndpoint
```

Setting the default subscription bevore retrieving the VM solved it:

```
Set-AzureSubscription -DefaultSubscription XXX
```

Maybe that helps you too